# How to include a library in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am writing an application using Symfony.  I have some reusable components that I don't want to put into the main Symfony modules; instead, they are in the `lib` directory.

What I want to know is, what is the best way to include this file?  Can I `include lib/foo/bar.php` or do I need a full path, or is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Symfony, but these links should help You. Besides, because I am new to this forum, stackowerfolow lets me post just 1 link, so my second link will be explanation how to find it. ;)

1. http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/92916/
2. Google: **The Definitive Guide to symfony 1.2**         (should be still relevant) . There check the chapter 17 - "Extending Symfony" under the paragraph **Plugins** .

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to have the lib directory

```
sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir')
```